# Python - BAR_CHART_RACE - Broken Pipe Error

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have the dataframe created in wide format that's needed for bar chart race. But when I run the code, i get a broken pipe error.I have installed all the packages that it needs.

Appreciate your help!

Code:
import bar_chart_race as bcr
bcr.bar_chart_race(df_join)

BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

CalledProcessError: Command '['ffmpeg', '-f', 'rawvideo', '-vcodec', 'rawvideo', '-s', '926x504', '-pix_fmt', 'rgba', '-r', '20.0', '-loglevel', 'error', '-i', 'pipe:', '-vcodec', 'h264', '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p', '-y', '/tmp/wsuser/tmpl289qyii/temp.m4v']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
1 import bar_chart_race as bcr
----> 2 bcr.bar_chart_race(df_join)

Comment: @TedPetrou  It appears to em as if you don't have ffmpeg installed.

Comment: I installed the ffmpeg using "!pip install --pre /project_data/data_asset/ffmpeg_python-0.2.0-py3-none-any.whl". But i still get the error. Not sure what I am missing.

Comment: are you on windows?

Comment: I think you need to be sure that ffmpeg is in your path.  Does `!ffmpeg -version` for within your Jupyter Notebook return anything?

Comment: @ScottBoston Jupyter notebook is hosted in linux server. And it returns "Requirement already satisfied: ffmpeg-python==0.2.0 from file:///project_data/data_asset/ffmpeg_python-0.2.0-py3-none-any.whl in /opt/conda/envs/Python-3.6-WMLCE/lib/python3.6/site-packages (0.2.0)". thanks for your help.

Comment: ffmpeg version 4.2.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 7.2.0 (crosstool-NG fa8859cb)
configuration: --prefix=/opt/conda/envs/Python-3.6-WMLCE --pkg-config=/opt/anaconda3/conda-bld/ffmpeg_1583242831994/_build_env/bin/pkg-config --cc=/opt/anaconda3/conda-bld/ffmpeg_1583242831994/_build_env/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc --disable-doc --enable-gpl --enable-avresample --disable-gnutls --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-libfreetype --disable-openssl --enable-libvpx --enable-pthreads --enable-libopus --enable-postproc --enable-pic --enable-pthreads --

Comment: hrm...  does the tutorials work?  `import bar_chart_race as bcr`
`df = bcr.load_dataset('covid19_tutorial')`
`bcr.bar_chart_race(df)`?

Comment: Just trying to eliminate data errors.

Comment: @ScottBoston I tried with the COVID data that works in general. Dataframe looks good. But i get the same error. /opt/conda/envs/Python-3.6-WMLCE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bar_chart_race/_make_chart.py:286: UserWarning: FixedFormatter should only be used together with FixedLocator
  ax.set_yticklabels(self.df_values.columns)
/opt/conda/envs/Python-3.6-WMLCE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bar_chart_race/_make_chart.py:287: UserWarning: FixedFormatter should only be used together with FixedLocator
  ax.set_xticklabels([max_val] * len(ax.get_xticks()))
MovieWriter stderr: Unknown encoder 'h264'